# tomcat 7.0 + JSF + CDI support in intellij idea

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, cdi, weld

I get this error during tomcat load:

C:\Projects\asdf\ejb7\out\artifacts\ejb7_war_exploded\WEB-INF\lib\weld-se.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class

I've created project with web and CDI support in Intellij IDEA. What's wrong here?

Thanx.

Comment: You probably have two versions of Weld in the classpath, check that out.

Comment: no, only one weld in WEB-INF

Comment: Maybe the other is in Tomcat's lib? (if you're using TomEE, it certainly is)

Comment: no, no weld there. I use tomcat, not tomcatEE. TomcatEE is not able to launch under IntelliJ

Comment: and if you remove it from WEB-INF, what error do you get?

Comment: If you mean TomEE it works fine with IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the weld-servlet jar instead of the SE jar.